# Separating one column into several columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssms, ssms-2016

Okay. This is a little bit complicated for me to explain and I am not even sure there is a way to do this using SSMS or MS Excel. Let's start...

I would like to do data analysis for a family-owned company. We use ERP system which has the option to export some sales reports. I would like to see our sales from last year for a specific item and sales representers and other analysis. However, I have a column and right below that column, there is another column which has different information and data type. I attached an example which describes the situation better than me.

Job# column overlaps with Item Price (which shows as NULL), date column overlaps with service price and job type column overlaps with total price column for every job.

Date column shows 43525 instead of March 1, 2018 and if I try to change this to date column then it affects the service price column. Although, it doesn't let me to change it.

It would be nice if I can separate those columns which overlap[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG7QV.jpg) one another. Any suggestion would work. Is there a way to do it dynamically using SSMS or Excel?

Thanks in advance for your time!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riHtw.jpg)

Comment: We need more info.  What is the format of the export? is it CSV? XLS? DOC? TXT? And can you vary the format before the export is done? (What is the ERP system? and version?)  Do you then import that file into Excel or into SSMS?  Please attach a sanitized export file that has 40 or 50 rows, so that we can talk about common data.

Comment: Yes you can import this kind of data but it's difficult to do this in any standard way because most import tools require consistent tabular data. The two basic solutions are: 1. Import into SQL Server as a single column and split inside SQL Server; 2. Write some powershell or something to pre-split the data into consistent seperate files and import those files.